# Finding the total from a single dimensional array - COBOL

Tags: cobol

I need to iterate through a 1D array and add all of the elements together to find the total.  I must use a Perfrom ... Varying statement, this is what I have come up with so far.

```
 perform 100-read-input-file  
           varying emp-rec-calls(ws-emp-total)
           from 1 by ws-emp-total 
           until (ws-eof-flag = 'Y'
                  OR ws-array-counter > ws-array-max)
       add emp-rec-calls(ws-emp-total) to ws-total-temp
```

The code for 100-read-input-file is simply

```
read input-file at end move 'y' to found-eof.
```

The problem I am currently getting is "Subscript out of range:" on this line "perform 100-read-input-file".  All help is appretiated, thanks!

Comment: Also, 01 found-eof                     pic x value 'N'.
           88 is-end-of-file                  value "Y".

Comment: Edit that into the question please

Comment: Can you provide a sample code that can be run in something like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cobol_online.php See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze the code you provided:

```
perform 100-read-input-file  
        varying emp-rec-calls(ws-emp-total)
           from 1 by ws-emp-total 
            until (ws-eof-flag = 'Y'
                  OR ws-array-counter > ws-array-max)
       add emp-rec-calls(ws-emp-total) to ws-total-temp
```

This loop doesn't really make any sense. You are saying perform this loop varying occurance X of the array EMP-REC-CALLS from 1 by X until a flag that never gets set within the loop is equal to yes OR a counter you are not incrementing is greater than the array size.

I think you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
PERFORM VARYING WS-ARRAY-COUNTER
           FROM 1 BY 1
          UNTIL WS-ARRAY-COUNTER > WS-ARRAY-MAX
   ADD EMP-REC-CALLS(WS-COUNTER) TO WS-TOTAL-TEMP
END-PERFORM
```

This will vary the counter WS-ARRAY-COUNTER by 1 every iteration of the loop (starting at 1) until that counter is greater than the max defined.